# Recording Vehicles passing at high speed: which type of microphone 4 the job?

Tags: field-recording, equipment

I have been tasked to capture the sound of various vehicles racing past me at high speed on a circuit.

My question is, what sort of microphone would you all recommend for the job?

At the moment all I have is an original Zoom H4 with a rycote windshield.

I have been looking into purchasing a sound devices location recorder for a while now. But I do not know what mic set up would be best suited to this task...

Its a big project with many recordings required, so I don't mind investing a lot of money into getting a decent semi pro/pro set up, specifically suited to this task.

any help is greatly appreciated.

I guess I need something directional to record the sounds of the vehicles and eliminate unwanted ambience/crowd noise at race events etc. But it also needs to handle high SPL I think... please correct me if Im wrong in thinking this any guidance is greatly appreciated.

- Si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://designingsound.org/2010/02/charles-deenen-special-car-recording-guide/

Comment: nice one Jay, I should have looked through the designing sound site for answers myself! I'm going to read through this article now... just had a quick browse and it seems to be recording vehicles when they are stationary mainly.... which will be useful but I also wan tho record them as they whizz by on the track... thanks again. I will look more closely at the article now.

Answer (score 0):

[Location Sound Effects Recording](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eb_7SHmMy_E&feature=relmfu)